# Excluding null values in order to divide one list by another

Tags: python, list, null

I have two lists: `total_price` and `units_b`, which both contain null values and I have an expression to divide total_price by units_b:

```
    total_price = [None, None, 10, 20]
    units_b = [None, None, 1, 2]

    average_price = [(x/y) for x, y in zip(total_price, units_b)]
```

Trying to run `average_price` gives me an error saying that I can't divide two 'NoneTypes'. Is there any way that I can exclude the null values for the division but perserve the integrity of the original list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
total_price = [None, None, 10, 20]
units_b = [None, None, 1, 2]

average_price = [(x/y) for x, y in zip(total_price, units_b) if x is not None and y is not None]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
average_price = [(x/y) for x, y in zip(total_price, units_b) if x is not None and y is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
average_price = [(x/y) for x, y in zip(total_price, units_b) if not (x==None or y==None)]
```

Although you should really [read the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)